# How to create multiples cPanel account using scripts

Tags: cpanel, accounts

I would like to specify these things:

> Domain|Username|Password|Contact Email|Package|IP Address

Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is my scripts:

> ! /bin/bash

make a file (/root/test1) which contains domain names, username and password.

```
for i in cat /root/test1 do domain=echo $i | cut -f1 -d: un=echo $i | cut -f2 -d: pw=echo $i | cut -f3 -d: /scripts/wwwacct $domain $un $pw 0 done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following command in your scripts.

```
/scripts/wwwacct domain.com newuser password 0 x3 n n n  0 0 0 0 0 0

The above creates a new account with the domain called domain.com
It sets their username to new user
It sets their pasword to password
Quota is unlimited
Theme is x3
Dedicated IP is not assigned
CGI is turned off
FrontPage is turned off
Maxftp is unlimted
The number of databases is unlimited
The number of email accounts they can create is unlimited
The amount of mailing lists is unlimited
The number of subdomains is unlimited
Bandwidth is unlimited.
```